# How do i find the highest lowest and average numbers when im closing the Form/Program and also each X minutes?

Tags: c#

For now i will pass the X minutes i will not doing it for now.
For the rest this is the code im using now.

I tried to do it this way:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DannyGeneral;
namespace CpuUsage
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private PerformanceCounter theCPUCounter;
        private PerformanceCounter theMemCounter;
        private PerformanceCounter specProcessCPUCounter;
        private float cpuUsage;
        private float memUsage;
        private string processname;
        private List<float> Values;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Values = new List<float>();
                theCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total");
                theMemCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
                specProcessCPUCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);


        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            memUsage = theMemCounter.NextValue();
            label1.Text = memUsage.ToString();
            Logger.Write("Memory Usage   " + memUsage.ToString());
            cpuUsage = this.theCPUCounter.NextValue();
            label2.Text = cpuUsage.ToString();
            Logger.Write("Cpu Usage   " + this.cpuUsage.ToString());
            Values.Add(cpuUsage);
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {

            float Maximum = Values.Max();
            float Minimum = Values.Min();
            float Average = Values.Average();
            string t = string.Format("{0}Maximum,{1}Minimum,{2}Average", Maximum, Minimum, Average);
            Logger.Write(t);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the result in the logger text file is like this:

```
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Memory Usage   2683
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Cpu Usage   0
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Memory Usage   2681
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Cpu Usage   5.951914
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Memory Usage   2675
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Cpu Usage   1.15339
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Memory Usage   2674
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Cpu Usage   4.230328
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Memory Usage   2674
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Cpu Usage   1.345688
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Memory Usage   2677
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Cpu Usage   4.422635
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Memory Usage   2676
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Cpu Usage   0.768766
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Memory Usage   2676
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Cpu Usage   0.5764585
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Memory Usage   2676
8/29/2012--1:57 AM ==> Cpu Usage   8.076494
8/29/2012--1:58 AM ==> 8.076494Maximum,0Minimum,2.947297Average
```

The last line the Format is not like i wanted it to be.
I wanted it to be something like: Maximum --- 8.076494 , Minimum --- 0 , Average --- 2.947297

But now im getting first the values then the text and without spaces between the values and each text.

My only problem now is the last line the string.Format

About every 5 minutes i will pass it for now will not doing it now.

Comment: Your edit is a completely new question... I had to vote it down.

Comment: I agree with you Tilo about it being a new question.  But I answered it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

1.) You don't need to save all the intermediate values, so a List is too much.
2.) Yes it will.
3.) Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // ...
    private float minCpu;
    private float maxCpu;
    private float sumCpu;
    private int ticks;

    // also call this in constructor
    private void reset()
    {
       this.minCpu = Single.PositiveInfinity;
       this.maxCpu = Single.NegativeInfinity;
       this.sumCpu = 0;
       this.ticks  = 0;
    }

    // ...
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
        // update
        if (this.minCpu > cpuUsage) this.minCpu = cpuUsage;
        if (this.maxCpu < cpuUsage) this.maxCpu = cpuUsage;
        this.sumCpu += cpuUsage;
        this.ticks++;

        if (this.ticks >= 5 * 60) // = 5 min, since this is called every second
        {
            float avgCpu = this.sumCpu / this.ticks;
            // write this.minCpu, this.maxCpu, and avgCpu to Log
            reset();
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

4.) No you don't. See above.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is the string format??? ok here you go:

```
 string t = string.Format("Maximum --- {0} , Minimum --- {1} , Average --- {2}", Maximum, Minimum, Average);
```

I honestly have no idea how you could have written the rest and not be able to figure that out.  I suggest getting some sleep.